# Is there a way to shuffle series’ in VLC or some type of video player, to play series at random but episodes in order?

Tags: automation, scripting

I am hopefully trying to figure out if their is a script or a way to program VLC/ multimedia player to randomly shuffle series of shows, but when it hits the same show it will play it in order. So I guess what I aim to do is have a video player shuffle random shows,  it in chronological order for that show.

Ex.: Lost S01E01, The Office S01E01, Game of Thrones S01E01, etc. Then if it shuffles and is playing the same series it would go Game of Thrones S01E02, The Office S01E02, Lost S01E02, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As I've moved over from VLC to GOM Player a couple years ago, I cannot vouch for the ealier anymore, but I'd say the easiest solution would be creating a simple playlist with whatever episodes you like. Such lists, as you probably know, since the old days of audio playlists only, can be put on shuffle mode at the press of a button and there you go: you'll have episodes being played randomly according to your request!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried kodi smart playlist? supposedly it does what you ask for?

Comment: This is not an answer to the question

Comment: I am looking for an answer myself and no one has provided valuable response yet, there are only vague suggestions floating around online, one of which I have posted here but couldn't get to work myself yet.